# Getting one specific field from a table in a db and using it in sessions php

Tags: php, session

I'm currently building a website that has a log in form. Depending on which role this user has a navigation bar has to be displayed accordingly.

For Example : Someone who hasn't yet logged in will have a "login" link.
If someone has logged in and is not an admin a different nav bar is displayed.

All log in details are stored in a db and this has to be done using sessions since it will send the user to a different page.

Any ideas ?

Code till now :

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_users
            WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pass'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
        or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$counter = $row[0];

if($counter > 0)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']= $username;
    $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow , You always have to provide sample of your code that you have attempt and what error you are having , we cannot write a code for you , you have to attempt your self first and then ask here if you have any problem.

Comment: Forgot to add it @Arsh Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a somewhat vague question but, check your role.

```
if($_SESSION['role']=='admin')
    echo 'I am admin';
elseif($_SESSION['role']=='customer')
    echo 'I am customer';
else
    echo 'No valid role / not logged in';
```

Comment: I have made use of this code, but after I log in and redirect to another page, no menu is loading. 

this is the code i have in the page after log in is made
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['role'] == "registered"){
  require_once('regnav.php');
 }
?>